# Keeping mongoose functions separately in nodejs app with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to keep some mongoose functions separately for a neater code, i want to deal with promises, below is an illustration.

Model.js File

```
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback); 
        });
    });
}
```

Here createUser is a custom function, and my route.js is as below,

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.createUser(newUser)
        .then(function(user){
            console.log(user)
            res.redirect('/users/login');
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })

})
```

With promises this shows an error of ".then undefined" and ".save() is not a function"

please correct me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't working because `createUser(..)` doesn't return a `promise`. In order for `.then()` to function, it should be chained to a function which returns a promise.

You have to return a promise from `createUser()`:

```
module.exports.createUser = function(newUser){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if(err){reject(err);}// err is passed on to the catch() call
                newUser.password = hash;
                resolve(newUser); // newUser is passed on to the then() call chained after the call to createUser()
            });
        });
    })
}
```

This should work:

```
module.exports.createUser = function(newUser){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
                bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                    if(err){reject(err);}// err is passed on to the catch() call
                    newUser.password = hash;
                    newUser.save(function(err, newUser){
                        if(err){return reject(err);}                        
                        resolve(newUser); // newUser is passed on to the then() call chained after the call to createUser()
                    })
                });
            });
        })
    }
```

Check out [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for more info.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But here where are we running .save() ?? so that it saves in mongoose

Comment: It worked, thx, but din understand about where save is happening??

Comment: Run it inside .then().

Comment: So can't I run it in the createUser function in the model.js file

Comment: In case of error you should "return reject(err)", without the return statement the user will be still inserted in mongo (at least the execution will be performed)

Comment: Right. My mistake. Edited.